# shared functionality between C# console apps

Tags: c#, inheritance, console-application, abstraction

I have two console apps, Query and Update, that share some functionality.  I wanted to have the two classes inherit from a common base class, but the problem is that, for a console app, I have to have a `static Main` function.  What I currently have is the following:

```
namespace Utils
{
    public class ConsoleBase
    {
        protected const int ERROR_EXIT_CODE = 1;
        protected static void printWarning(string msg) {...}
        public ConsoleBase(IEnumerable<string> args) { ... }
...

namespace Update
{
    class Update : ConsoleBase
    {
        private static ConsoleBase _consoleBase;
        public static void Main(string[] args) { ... }
...

namespace Query
{
    class Query : ConsoleBase
    {
        private static ConsoleBase _consoleBase;
        public static void Main(string[] args) { ... }
...
```

It seems like a design problem for me to both inherit from `ConsoleBase` as well as have an instance of it as a `static` variable within each derived class.  The reason I'm doing this is so that:

1. I can have `protected static` methods defined in `ConsoleBase` that are accessible to other `static` methods in the derived classes.
2. I can pass along command-line arguments to the constructor for `ConsoleBase`, do common stuff, and then access the arguments again in the derived classes via `public` properties and methods on the instance of `ConsoleBase`.

So in the derived classes, I have a mixture of calls to methods/properties on the instance of `ConsoleBase`, e.g.

```
_consoleBase.UseDebugMode()
```

As well as calling inherited static methods and accessing inherited constants that are defined in `ConsoleBase`, e.g.

```
printWarning(CONST_MSG_IN_BASE_CLASS);
```

Can I clean this up somehow?  Is it bad to both inherit from a class as well as keep an instance of that base class around for working with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix static and instance methods like this.

Consider, separating the responsibility that the static methods provide into a different class that you can inherit from. Make the non-static functionality a separate class that you aggregate and instantiate within Update and Query.

Besides, if Update and Query are derivatives of ConsoleBase - why do you need the aggregate instances?

Comment: I like the idea of separating my `static` methods in `ConsoleBase` from the instance methods.  Now, if I can think of good names for the two classes...

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can define a base class with a protected static main, then call BaseClass.Main(args) from the Main method in the inheriting classes.

This syntex is more correct:

```
public class BaseApp
{
    public static Main(String[] args)
    {
        // TODO: ...
    }
}

public class App1 : BaseApp // Same for App2
{
    // There is no need to keep a reference of the base class
    // if you are accessing static methods only

    public static Main(String[] args)
    {
        BaseApp.Main(args); // Access via class, not via instance
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to do that. Why don't you simply call the ConsoleBase.Main() function with your command line arguments?

Having an instance of the base class is a design problem.

Comment: I want the command-line arguments to be stored as instance variables since they won't be known until run-time.  If I have a `static` Main function in `ConsoleBase`, I won't be able to access those instance variables in that `static` function.